# Disable doubleclick zooming in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, zoom

I've searched for it on the entire web and finally I found on artamstrong.com how to disable a single feature like "mouseWheelZoom".

Here is how doubleclick zooming in OpenLayers 3 can be disabled:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    controls : ol.control.defaults()
                .extend([ new ol.control.FullScreen() ]),
    interactions : ol.interaction.defaults({doubleClickZoom :false}),
    target : 'map',
    layers : [ new ol.layer.Tile({
            title : 'OpenStreetMaps',
            preload : Infinity,
            source : new ol.source.OSM(),
            visible : true
    }) ],
    view : new ol.View({
            center : ol.proj.transform([ 9.41, 48.82 ], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
            zoom : 12
    })
});
```

It's really that simple, just tell ol3 to set "doubleClickZoom" on false:

```
interactions : ol.interaction.defaults({doubleClickZoom :false})
```

Comment: Hi Brain, Welcome to GIS@Se, this is incredibly useful information, but this site requires the posting of specific questions and answers. Feel free to edit your question to make it a Question, and then answer it with your solution. People who post questions are able to answer their own questions.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to disable doubleClickZoom after map initialization, here is the way:

```
var dblClickInteraction;
// find DoubleClickZoom interaction
map.getInteractions().getArray().forEach(function(interaction) {
  if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom) {
    dblClickInteraction = interaction;
  }
});
// remove from map
map.removeInteraction(dblClickInteraction);
```

You can also remove or add interaction such as PinchZoom, KeyboardZoom, etc,. with the same way.

Comment: In Array, you can use `find` instead of `forEach`:



```const dblClickInteractio = map.getInteraction().getArray().find((interaction ) => {
      return interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom
})
```

Comment: @YairTawil Good to know. but, is there an advantage to use `find` instead `forEach`?

Comment: Sure,  find will break the loop... forEach will always run n times

Comment: If there's multiple interactions, `filter` can be used as well.

Comment: Should be map.getInteractions().getArray() with an 's' on the end of getInteractions(), not getInteraction. Though actually a much cleaner answer is in the question....

Comment: @mwarren good catch!

Answer (score 2):

For OL 3 & 4 you can use [ol.interaction.defaults](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.html#.defaults) as explained in the below answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29967145/1225421

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/195879/86845