# Disabling map drag and zoom in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2

I need to disable all map interactions, like map zoom, drag, scroll zoom, any kind of interaction.

Is there some easy way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't try this code but I hope it does the work :

```
var Interactions=yourMap.getInteractions();
for(var interaction in Interactions){
    yourMap.removeInteraction(interaction);
}
```

this is for OL3

Edits :

when declaring the map, set the interactions to false within its attributes :

```
interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
    doubleClickZoom :false,
    dragAndDrop: false,
    keyboardPan: false,
    keyboardZoom: false,
    mouseWheelZoom: false,
    pointer: false,
    select: false
}),
```

and then using the method

```
ol.interaction.setActive(true);
```

you can re-enable them again, somehow setActive(false) didn't work for me, so here is a work around if it suits your needs

Comment: Nope, still I can drag and zoom.

Comment: how about defining the interactions "false" when you declare the map like this : interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({doubleClickZoom :false}),
and so one for each interaction : 
            dragAndDrop
            keyboardPan
            keyboardZoom
            mouseWheelZoom
            pointer
            select

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want any interactions, just put *interactions:null* into your map constructor like that :

```
var map = new ol.Map({
   interaction:null
});
```

If you don't want zoom buttons and info button, just put *controls: null* into your map constructor again

```
var map = new ol.Map({
   interaction: null,
   control: null
});
```

There you go : [a working fiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/tmylamoule/48n5L69b/1/)

Comment: is interactions not interaction

Answer (score 3):

`map.getInteractions().forEach(x => x.setActive(false));`

Works also with `setActive(true)` to re-enable interactions.

Answer (score 2):

Openlayers 5

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  ...
  controls: [],
  interactions: []
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Shamelessly copied from another answer. Do this for each interaction type (MouseWheelZoom, PinchZoom, etc.)

```
var dblClickInteraction;
// find DoubleClickZoom interaction
map.getInteractions().getArray().forEach(function(interaction) {
  if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom) {
    dblClickInteraction = interaction;
  }
});
// remove from map
map.removeInteraction(dblClickInteraction);
```

Comment: please add link to the other answer

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.